# Update unique values/combinations of concatenated columns from another table

Tags: postgresql, join, count, concatenation, distinct

I have `table2` contains around **26 columns & 2mln rows**.

| a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j | k | l | m | n | o | p | q | r | s | t | u | v | w | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18 | 2 | 2 | 22 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 26 | 2 | 0 | 22 | 0 | 22 | 2 | 32 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 20 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 24 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 10 | 2 | 2 | 222 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 24 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 2 |
| 12 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 21 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 22 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 0 |
| 15 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 21 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 22 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 0 |
| 20 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 4 | 20 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 22 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 0 |
| 15 | 2 | 2 | 22 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 21 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 22 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 0 |
| 18 | 2 | 2 | 22 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 21 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 22 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 0 |
| 8 | 2 | 0 | 22 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 24 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 0 | 2 |
| 14 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 12 | 0 | 2 | 22 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 22 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 2 |
| 14 | 2 | 0 | 222 | 0 | 22 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 20 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 0 | 22 |

And `table1.joins` around **918,555** rows which is concatenated headers of 26 columns `(a:z)` from `table2`

| id | sets | joins | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | a,b | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | a,c,f,i | 0 |
| 3 | 5 | a,d,o,x,y | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | a,e | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | a,f | 0 |
| 6 | 3 | a,g,x | 0 |
| 7 | 2 | a,h | 0 |
| 8 | 5 | a,i,l,r,s | 0 |
| 9 | 2 | a,j | 0 |
| 10 | 2 | a,k | 0 |

The concatenated `2-7 sets` of columns in `table1` are based on the below criteria's;

```
2 sets of concatenated data from 26 columns = 325 rows/combinations (like “a,b”, “a,c”, “a,d”…...)
3 sets of concatenated data from 26 columns = 2,600 rows/combinations (like “a,b,c”, “a,b,d”, “a,b,e”……)
4sets of concatenated data from 26 columns  = 14,950 rows/combinations (like “a,b,c,d”, “a,b,c,e”, “a,b,c,f”……)
5sets of concatenated data from 26 columns = 65,780 rows/combinations (like “a,b,c,d,e”, “a,b,c,d,f”, “a,b,c,d,g”……)
6sets of concatenated data from 26 columns = 177,100 rows/combinations (like “a,b,c,d,e,f”, “a,b,c,d,e,g”, “a,b,c,d,e,h”……)
7sets of concatenated data from 26 columns = 657,800 rows/combinations (like “a,b,c,d,e,f,g”, “a,b,c,d,e,f,h”, “a,b,c,d,e,f,i”……)
```

I want each of those concatenated columns’ result from `table2` to be updated in `table1` after counting a unique values/combinations only.

Tried this basic code, but getting an error.

```
update table1 set result = (SELECT COUNT (*) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT (select concat(joins) from table1) FROM table2) as dists);
```

The expected unique result looks like this;

```
   joins   | result
-----------+--------
 a,b       |      7
 a,c,f,i   |      9
 a,d,o,x,y |     11
 a,e       |      7
 a,f       |      9
 a,g,x     |     10
 a,h       |     10
 a,i,l,r,s |     10
 a,j       |      9
 a,k       |      9
```

Comment: Please **do not post data images**; see [Why should I not upload images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Instead post formatted text. A good place to create formatted text tables is [Senseful Solutions](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/). Update your question by placing the results between lines containing only **```**.

Comment: Consider [plpgsql dynamic commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). If you added your sample data as text, we could immediately reproduce your setup, test a solution and post an answer with a working example.

Comment: I have added the table as text, but the format is somehow not accurate

Comment: Pls. add a few lines of the expected result

Comment: for instance, a,f=9 and a,c,f,i =9 because in both results there are duplicates which is excluded from counting. (9 out of total 11 rows)

Comment: Have you considered unnesting the rows and joining the tables together, then aggregating by row value and column name, and counting the distinct results? Someone would invariably mention what you have is not proper relational design, but I'm guessing it's too late to rework that.

Comment: No, I haven't considered, can you please provide the query so that we can test, it may work

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74953842/updating-a-column-by-counting-matches-from-another-table-multiple-columns#comment132271001_74953842): you can use [plpgsql dynamic commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) to construct your queries:

```sql
do $$ 
declare 
  rec record;
  current_joins text;
  current_result int;
begin
  for rec in select joins from table1 loop
     select rec.joins into current_joins;
     execute format('select count(*) 
                     from (
                        select distinct %1$s
                        from table2 
                     ) as some_alias;',
                     current_joins) 
              into current_result;
     update table1 set result=current_result where joins=current_joins;
  end loop;
end $$;
```

Which simply loops over your "joins" and executes your query once for each of them, updating the corresponding "result" field:

```sql
select * from table1;
   joins   | result
-----------+--------
 a,b       |      7
 a,c,f,i   |      9
 a,d,o,x,y |     11
 a,e       |      7
 a,f       |      9
 a,g,x     |     10
 a,h       |     10
 a,i,l,r,s |     10
 a,j       |      9
 a,k       |      9
```

[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/q9lnyXmv). Above is to show the principle - I don't expect you actually want one random "count" as your result. It'd help if you explained your logic a bit more, maybe adding an clarified example result.

Comment: the outcome of a,c,f,i will be 9 because based on the below code total rows/results are 9  `SELECT a,c,f,i,
count (*) FROM table2 GROUP BY
a,c,f,i
HAVING count(*) >=1 order by count desc`

Comment: @Gulya I've updated the answer and the linked demo.

Comment: tried the code but the following error is occurring, some of my columns are in text format maybe that's why. `ERROR:  column "o" does not exist
LINE 5:                         group by product,m/f
                                             ^
QUERY:  select count(*) 
                     from (
                        select 1
                        from table2 
                        group by product,m/f 
                        having count(*)>=1 
                     ) as some_alias;
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 9 at EXECUTE
SQL state: 42703`

Comment: Edit the question and add this error and exactly what code you've tried - from the error message it's clear you've modified something or tried this with some other structures/data.

Comment: @  Zegarek i have tried with different data but with almost same structure, only some of the columns are in text format. Let's assume the columns 2,3,4,5,6,12,13 and 14 from the above table2 is in text format. so in this case does the above code work plz?

Comment: It makes no difference if their data type is `int` or `text`. You can modify the demo, hit "run" and see that it's still working. [Here's one where I did exactly that](https://dbfiddle.uk/nGKfJKgG). Your error message is pretty clear: the table you're using doesn't have an "o" column - I asked for the exact code that caused it because in some cases it could be a simple typo. Properly formatted, unedited error message would be useful too, because there's an `^` that points directly at where the problem is.

Comment: Basically in my original data in table2, there are another 12 columns before column **a** and even there are another 50 columns after column **cc** (only columns a:cc (13 to 41) is related to tbale1). Maybe this could be the reason of error message?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The error says there are too few, not too many columns. Have you checked for misspelled column names?

Comment: @  Zegarek i have amended the table almost same like my original data where the table & error message can be seen from the following link [https://dbfiddle.uk/Ha1TDiU4]

Comment: You need to quote column names with special characters https://dbfiddle.uk/pP_9mKy3 I just added `"` around `"m/f"`.

Comment: Hi Zegarek, both of tables are having more than a mln records and the code is taking more than hours to complete just a few rows only. Is there a way to amend the code so that the report can be completed within a few minutes please. What if we add this code in between of the current code `select count(distinct %1$s) from table2`

Comment: Seems like even though it's simpler and more elegant, it's actually slower with more rows: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Xf1ROZAy)

Comment: Yes, it's slower than the previous code. What if we first **union** all the columns of table2 based on joins in table1 than counting/updating the table, it's just an idea but i don't know whether it will be faster or no

Comment: I'm more inclined to use [`grouping sets`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS) or just `cube`. It could potentially eliminate the need for a loop and plpgsql would only be needed to pull grouping sets from the table and plug them into a single query.

Comment: @  Zegarek appreciate if you could support with the above please. tried with different ways, but no solution

Comment: Sure, I'll see if I can take another look. I've tried a few loose ideas earlier, but [none](https://dbfiddle.uk/XhA4oVEu) of them worked better than the initial solution. `cube` and `grouping sets` turned out to be a dead end - one's inapplicable to this, the other isn't worth it.

Comment: As per my calculation the above code will take 4,11 month to complete the entire data, like `900,000 rows * 12 secs per row = 10,800,000 sec,  and 10,800,000 sec / 86,400 seconds a day = 125 days,  and 125 days / 30.417 days a month = 4.11 months`

Comment: You could've just `select justify_interval(9e5*'12 seconds'::interval);` :)
Depending on how this scales, if you split this into batches processed by a number of workers, you can finish it in a few days, nights or runs whenever there's less traffic. After that, if you can afford to have some increased latency, you can keep table1 maintained with triggers that watch all operations on table2. How many columns do you actually have in table2? How many rows are there in table1/how many combinations of table2 columns are you planning to keep stats for? What's the traffic on table2 like?

Comment: The table2 contains around 60 columns & 2mln rows, but only 26 columns (a:cc) are related/linked to table1 and the remaining is some other data which I don’t need them in table1

The data in table1 is basically concatenated headers of those 26 columns (a:cc) from table2, and the outcome looks like [as following;](https://dbfiddle.uk/hSvV8TwN)

And, I want each of those concatenated columns’ result to be updated in table1 after counting a unique values/combinations only.

Comment: Hi Experts, appreciate if someone could support me with the above request please. Thanks in advance

Comment: @  Zegarek appreciate if you could support with any other alternative query/solution which could complete the data faster please. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The first point that should be made is this is not proper relational structure.

Assuming you have no control over this, one thought is to do an unnest of each table then join them together:

```
select id, joins,
  unnest(string_to_array(joins, ',')) as col_name
from table1

select row_number() over(order by 1) as rowNr,
unnest(array['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']) AS col_name,
unnest(array[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z]) AS col_value
from table2
```

Edit: This will likely be faster using a Lateral join on table2, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74979966/how-to-count-update-a-single-column-with-unique-value-of-multiple-columns-from-a) in a previous answer to your questions.

Then you could join them together and string_agg column name and column value in table2 grouping by table1 id and RowNr to help you get your unique results. Something like this.

```
select t1.id, t1.joins,
  string_agg(t2.col_name || '_' ||  
    cast(t2.col_value as varchar), ',' order by t2.col_name ) as row_vals
```

It would then be a matter of counting distinct row values per id.

I have no way of knowing how well this would perform and I did not include every column name. You would have to validate column names/test/check syntax compatibility with your version.

Comment: @ JJ32  tried the above, but getting an error, can you please check it  [https://dbfiddle.uk/GVzZTeKK]