# How to count/update a single column with unique value of multiple columns from another table

Tags: postgresql

I have table2 as below

| a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j | k | l | m | n | o | p | q | r | s | t | u | v | w | x | y | z | aa | bb | cc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18 | 2 | 2 | 22 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 26 | 2 | 0 | 22 | 0 | 22 | 2 | 32 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 20 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 24 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| 10 | 2 | 2 | 222 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 24 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 12 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 21 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 22 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| 15 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 21 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 22 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| 20 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 4 | 20 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 22 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| 15 | 2 | 2 | 22 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 21 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 22 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 9 |
| 18 | 2 | 2 | 22 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 21 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 22 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| 8 | 2 | 0 | 22 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 24 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 14 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 12 | 0 | 2 | 22 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 22 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 14 | 2 | 0 | 222 | 0 | 22 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 20 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 0 | 22 | 2 | 2 | 0 |

And table1 as following

| header | result |
| --- | --- |
| a |  |
| b |  |
| c |  |
| d |  |
| e |  |
| f |  |
| g |  |
| h |  |
| i |  |
| j |  |
| k |  |
| l |  |
| m |  |
| n |  |
| o |  |
| p |  |
| q |  |
| r |  |
| s |  |
| t |  |
| u |  |
| v |  |
| w |  |
| x |  |
| y |  |
| z |  |
| aa |  |
| bb |  |
| cc |  |

and would like to update table1.result with unique value from table2 based on the header.

Tried with below code, but there is an error. Any support is appreciated plz.

```
UPDATE table1 
SET result = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
              FROM 
                  (SELECT DISTINCT 
                       (SELECT header FROM table1) 
                   FROM table2) AS dists);
```

Comment: `(SELECT DISTINCT (select header from table1) FROM table2)` doesn't make sense. What did you intend this to do?

Comment: It seems you already know that this requires dynamic SQL. How is this different from your previous question [Updating a column by counting matches from another table multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74953842/updating-a-column-by-counting-matches-from-another-table-multiple-columns)?

Comment: this is completely different than my previous question. Here i just need a unique summery of each column of table2. For instance, in table1 row 1/a to be updated with unique value of column a from table2 and similar next rows also to be updated. Here is the [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/RVXzuRRV) of tables

Comment: I don't see the difference. Sure, it's only single columns now instead of sometimes grouping multiple columns together, but it's still the same counting of distinct values. The code from your previous still works for this (though maybe can simplified a little, getting rid of the `group by`), and the approach you need is **exactly** the same.

Comment: Demo of the old code on the new table: https://dbfiddle.uk/EEsMrz8G

Answer (score 1):

You can unpivot the original table to count distinct values per column:

```
select u.col, count(distinct u.val) as distinct_count
from table2 t2
  cross join lateral (
    values 
      ('a', a), ('b', b), ('c', c), ('d', d), ('e', e), ('f', f), ('g', g), ('h', h), ('i', i),
      ('j', j), ('k', k), ('k', k), ('l', l), ('m', m), ('n', n), ('o', o), ('p', p), ('q', q),
      ('r', r), ('s', s), ('s', s), ('t', t), ('u', u), ('v', v), ('w', w), ('x', x), ('y', z),
      ('aa', aa), ('bb', bb), ('cc', cc)
      
  ) as u(col, val)
group by u.col
```

This can be used to update the other table

```
update table1 
   set result = c.distinct_count
from (
  select u.col, count(distinct u.val) distinct_count
  from table2 t2
    cross join lateral (
      values 
        ('a', a), ('b', b), ('c', c), ('d', d), ('e', e), ('f', f), ('g', g), ('h', h), ('i', i),
        ('j', j), ('k', k), ('k', k), ('l', l), ('m', m), ('n', n), ('o', o), ('p', p), ('q', q),
        ('r', r), ('s', s), ('s', s), ('t', t), ('u', u), ('v', v), ('w', w), ('x', x), ('y', z),
        ('aa', aa), ('bb', bb), ('cc', cc)
      
    ) as u(col, val)
  group by u.col  
) as c 
where c.col = result.header;
```

Comment: Nice, but verbose! Do you think the cross join before the counting has a different performance than `select u.* from (select count(distinct a) as a, count(distinct b) as b, … from table2) cross join lateral (values ('a', a), …) as u(col, distinct_count)`?

Comment: I find the many `count(distinct ..)` more verbose than the unpivot. But they might indeed be faster.

Comment: On [their previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74953842/updating-a-column-by-counting-matches-from-another-table-multiple-columns), OP was ready to use dynamic SQL, so verbosity might not matter :-)